# Safari crisp-edges not supported?

Tags: html, css, image, safari, pixel

This is driving me absolutely nuts. I'm trying to upscale some pixel art and Safari isn't playing ball. This is the CSS I'm applying to the image:

```
.avatar {
width: 140px;
height: 224px;
image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;             /* Older versions of FF          */
image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;          /* FF 6.0+                       */
image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast; /* Safari                        */
image-rendering: -o-crisp-edges;            /* OS X & Windows Opera (12.02+) */
image-rendering: pixelated;                 /* Awesome future-browsers       */
-ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;   /* IE                            */
}
```

Now this works great in Chrome and looks like this: [image: crisp pixels]

But on Safari it renders this blurry mess: [image: blurry mess]

I'm using Safari 8.0 and every thread I've seen says this should be working. It's not. It's simply not. I'm aware there are solutions involving drawing on a canvas but come on.. it's 2015, I shouldn't have to jump through hoops to upscale with the most basic of upscaling algorithms.

Comment: When I checked in Safari 8 on browser stack, it is working for me with `image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast`. What is the version of Safari that you are using?